# Symfony. Easy admin 3. Field for json type with editable key and value

Tags: symfony, easyadmin3

I need to view, create and edit json keys and values ​​in easyadmin. Unfortunately, I can only add value. Is it possible to display and edit a key and its value?

**My easy admin version : 3.5.16**

**My Crud Controller**

```
class TestCrudController extends AbstractCrudController {

public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
{
    return Test::class;
}

public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    return [
        IdField::new('id')->hideOnForm(),
        TextField::new('name'),
        ArrayField::new('json'),
    ];
}

public function createEntity(string $entityFqcn)
{
   $test = new Test();

   $test->setJson([
       "Hight" => "134 mm",
       "Width" => "13 mm"
       ]);

   return $test;
}
```

[**Displayed by easy admin:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjohB.png)

After adding a new one
the element in the array. Key has the value "NaN"

Comment: maybe use custom fields [https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/1.x/book/edit-new-configuration.html#customizing-the-form-fields]